# Automated Export to CSV without SSIS & PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that generates 1.5M rows that I need to export on a daily basis. I'm trying to automate it and running into some issues.

Using the SSMS Export function works great, but we have SQL Web and apparently that doesn't support saving the SSIS package.

I tried a Powershell script, but that bombs because it's doing something in memory and it just increases to the point that the script fails.

What are my options to do this export as a scheduled task inside of SQL Server?

Comment: If you have the need to export 1.5M rows daily you probably should consider upgrading to Standard edition.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a huge export to me.  Unfortunately upgrading just to do this isn't really possible.